# How i can get the 2 decimal places?

Tags: highcharts

Based on this jsfiddle,

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/qq6o1ma1/5/

I would like display the figure as 77.00 instead of 77.0007825

```
chart.setTitle({
    text:  percent*100 + '%'
});
```

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
text:  (percent*100).toFixed(2) + '%'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4neop25f/